# Case function not working with discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started making my discord bot today and I am completely stuck,The first case works perfectly but for some reason the 2nd one doesn't work,I tested it many times and trying different things but every time I type !Mai nothing comes up and also there is no error so I have no idea. Please help.

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configuring logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initializing Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
            case 'Mai':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    messasge:'is the greatest!'
                })
                });
            break;
            // Case commands
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: you should have a break; after every case, unsure if that's the problem though.

Comment: Console and check what you are getting in cmd. Also, every case should have break statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a few mistakes while writing the switch statement:

- There's a typo in the key `message`
- Your brackets are placed wrong
- Each case should have a `break`

Your statement should look like this:

```
switch(cmd) {
  // !ping
  case 'ping':
    bot.sendMessage({
      to: channelID,
      message: 'Pong!'
    });
    break;
  case 'Mai':
    bot.sendMessage({
      to: channelID,
      message:'is the greatest!'
    });
    break;
  // Case commands
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,I am really stupid i started studying js a few weeks ago :D

Answer (score 1):

You have some bracket errors in your switch case. Take another look at it.

```js
switch(cmd) {
  // !ping
  case 'ping':
      bot.sendMessage({
           to: channelID,
           message: 'Pong!'
      });
      break;
  case 'Mai':
      bot.sendMessage({
           to: channelID,
           messasge:'is the greatest!'
      });
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your code: your first call to `sendMessage` lacks a bracket and a parenthesis:

```
    switch(cmd) {
        // !ping
        case 'ping':
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'Pong!'
            });
            break;
        case 'Mai':
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                messasge:'is the greatest!'
            });
        break;
        // Case commands
     }
```

Your first command is then executed but the second does really not exist so it can't be executed.